# run python function as command line when django is runing under docker

Tags: python, django, linux, docker

I am working on a django docker image and I want to execute a function ussing command line, I know that I can enter to shell python docker container and run a function like this :

- `docker container ls` to find the container id and use in the next command
- `docker container exec -it <container_id> python3 manage.py shell`
  Then:

```
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
>>> from xx import foo 
>>> foo()  # foo() has been excecuted
```

However, i was wondering if i can use something similar like python flag `-c` which help to run small piece of python code as command line like this:

- `python3 -c "from xx import foo; foo()"`

I tried to insert a cmd with linux tubes :
 `echo 'from xx import foo; foo()' | docker container exec -it <container_id> python3 manage.py shell`, However it doesn't work.

I'd appreciate any advice, thanks for your time.

Comment: You could call the function from a custom management command? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
docker exec -it <container id> python3 manage.py shell --command="import foo;foo()"
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#shell).